# Selecting the database and table name from a query stored in a String variable in java

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have a string which contains a query

```
String query=" select * from abc.xyz";
```

Where abc is my db name and xyz is my table name .
How can I get these two into two seperate variables in java

Comment: Split the string and check what comes after 'from'. If it has a '.' then split it again. The first part is the database the second is the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with split:

```
String[] parts = query.split(" ");
String part = parts[3]; // abc.xyz
parts = part.split(".");
String dbName = parts[0] // db name
String table = parts[1]  // table name
```

If you need to extract the bd name and the table name along dynamic queries you can do as follows:

```
String[] parts = query.split(" ");
int i;
for(i=0; i<query.lenght, i++){
    if(query[i].equals("from") || query[i].equals("FROM")){
        break;
    }
}
String part = parts[i++]; // abc.xyz
parts = part.split(".");
String dbName = parts[0] // db name
String table = parts[1]  // table name
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks,this works for the current case but what if my string variable keeps getting dynamic queries ,how do i do the same then ?

Comment: Can you give some variation of the dynamic query you are referring to @Nightwing

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.getSchema()
```

the get schema method of your connection object can get you the db if you are using single DB across your application.
Regarding the tablename.
If its a simple one then splitting everything after from can give you the tablename

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to find the database name start location. It is after the from key word then do the sub string.

You can try like this:

```
      String query=" select * from abc.xyz";
      String str = query.substring(query.indexOf("from")+5);
      String db = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('.'));
      String table = str.substring(str.indexOf('.')+1);

      System.out.println("db = "+db);
      System.out.println("table = "+table);
```